# how we can use proper soql query

Tags: soql

I have created a costum object, email. In this object I am storing date and sender.
Examples:

```
Date               sender
8/2/2013 4:00 AM   Amit
8/3/2013 4:00 AM   Jayant
8/3/2013 4:10 AM   Jony
```

I want to display the data in Visualforce page like this:

```
Date   8/3/2013
sender : Jony , Jayant //Here i want to display Jony 1st bcz same date but latest time.
---------------------------
Date   8/2/2013
sender : Amit
---------------------------
```

How can I write a SOQL query for this?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your sobject is defined as Email__c and that the fields are Date__c and Sender__c.

The query would be:

```
SELECT Date__c, Sender__c FROM Email__c ORDER BY Date__c DESC
```

You can then use visualforce to format your datetime value accordingly:

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,date,dd.MM.yyyy}">
    <apex:param value="{!object.dateValue}" /> 
</apex:outputText>
```

More info on visualforce outputText component can be found in the [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_outputText.htm).

EDIT: My mistake, I didn't realise it was really a question about aggregating values.

As user *[e-bacho 2.0](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/93/e-bacho-2-0)* pointed out in the comments below, the best way to solve this is with a map:

```
Map<Date, List <Sender__c>>
```

Comment: This won't work bcz i want to display date plus sender wise.

Comment: This soql will give me email object. if i used that object in repeat component i am getting output but how i can print date only once for same date sender then dotted line next again date and sender..

Comment: Date   8/3/2013
sender : Jony , Jayant

Comment: Date 8/2/2013 sender Amit

Comment: You will need a Map <Date, List <Sender__c>> in order to map multiple senders from the query for the same date before displaying them on the VF page as you desire. Have a look here - http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/01/06/fun-with-salesforce-collections/

Comment: A map is the obvious winner, good solution.

Comment: ya good but how i can store my objects. i think it should be  Map <Date, List <email__c>> then i can display info for that date..

Comment: plz share how i can write soql query for this?

Comment: The SOQL would be the one in my answer. You will then need to iterate over each row and add it to the map in apex. Use the map.contains() method to check if there is already an entry in the map for a given date.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Sender__c is a lookup to another object. That said here is an example code (not tested, there might be some syntax issues maybe):

```
Apex:

// In your class
Map <Date, List <Sender__c>> dateMap {get; set;}
List <Email__c> emails {get; set;}

// Inside your constructor or action method
dateMap = new Map <Date, List <Sender__c>> ();
List <Email__c> emails = [SELECT Date__c, Sender__c, Sender__r.Name FROM Email__c ORDER BY Date__c DESC];

for (Email__c email : emails)
{
    if (dateMap.get(email.Date__c) == null)
    {
        dateMap.put(email.Date__c, new List <Sender__c> ());
    }

    dateMap.get(email.Date__c).add(new Sender__c(Id = email.Sender__c, Name = email.Sender__r.Name));
}



VisualForce:

<apex:repeat value="{!emails}" var="email">
    Date:
    <apex:outputText value="{0,date,dd.MM.yyyy}">
        <apex:param value="{!email.Date__c}" /> 
    </apex:outputText>

    Sender:
    <apex:repeat value="{!dateMap[email.Date__c]}" var="sender">
        <apex:outputText value="{!sender.Name}" /><br/>
    </apex:repeat>

    ----------------
</apex:repeat>
```

I hope that's what you're after.